# What's the meaning of "reach out"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this statement:

> You are NOT worthless. Yes you deserve to think about whatever you want, it's not being selfish. Self-care is important. Have you **reached out** for help yet?

What's the meaning of *reach out*?

Comment: Did you try a dictionary? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reach+out

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Does it mean, definition #3 of the dictionary: reach out - attempt to communicate?

Comment: @Theo: Definition #1: *move forward or upward in order to touch; also in a metaphorical sense; "Government reaches out to the people"*  In this case, it is the metaphorical sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally, when

> one reaches out

one is extending their arm to grasp or hold *something*.

Metaphorically, **reach out** is also used to mean **make contact with** *someone*.
The telephone company, AT&T, had an ad campaign based on this, and the slogan was

> Reach out and touch someone.

The speaker is asking if you've contacted anyone for help.